# Problems with my code's logic to save pictures on the firebase storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, firebase, firebase-storage

I am facing problems to save my pictures in the firebase storage. I am sure it is a problem with how my code was build because, having space to save 4 pictures, only one is being saved.

In my database I have a table and inside this table i have the column "fotos", "medidor", "leitura", "desligado", I will have four items and in each item I can fulfill all of those camps. Each item I can save 1 photo. If I fullfil the three first camps for all those 4 items it'll sucessfully be saved on the database. But if I try to save photos for more than one item, only the first item will save the photo (both upload on the firabse storage and save the link on the database), other item's photos will not receive any action. I will leave here this part of code as it follows:

```
     if (FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance == null)
                {
              
                    FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
                    {
                        Credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault()
                    });
                }
                    
                var bucketName = "bucketname.appspot.com";

                #region Medidores
                if (model.Medidores != null && model.Medidores.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var item in model.Medidores)
                    {
                        var prop = item.Id > 0 ? db.VistoriasMedidors.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == item.Id) : new VistoriasMedidor();
                        prop.Desligado = item.Desligado;
                        var listaFotos = new List();


                        foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
                        {
                            if (fileName == "Medidores[" + item.Index + "].upFotos")
                            {
                                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                                {
                                    var fileName1 = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm}-{Guid.NewGuid()}-{file.FileName}";
                                    var IdVis = vistoria.Id.ToString();

                                    FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage(bucketName);

                                    var objectName = $"Medidores/{IdVis}/{fileName1}";
                                    using (var stream = file.InputStream)
                                    {
                                        await storage.Child(objectName).PutAsync(stream);
                                    }

                                    var fileUrl = await storage.Child(objectName).GetDownloadUrlAsync();
                                    listaFotos.Add(fileUrl);
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        prop.Fotos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaFotos);
                        prop.Leitura = item.Leitura;
                        prop.Medidor = item.Medida;

                        if (prop.Id == 0)
                        {
                            prop.IdVistoria = vistoria.Id;
                            prop.IdAppInterno = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                            prop.Tipo = item.Tipo;
                            db.VistoriasMedidors.Add(prop);
                            //db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

If anyone could point what I am missing for my code to behave like that, and why my code is behaving like that, I would be extremely thankful!

Comment: if anyone has any doubts about the problem, please, share it here and I will answer promptly